# How do I capture stdin (more than one line) to a String in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a Dart command-line program that want to be able to pipe data from the shell to the Dart program (e.g., `cat file.txt | dart my_program.dart` or accept input until the user uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>). Going through the tutorials online, the only documentation I found on saving input from the stdin was `stdin.readLineSync()`. However, as the name implies, this only reads the first line.

How can capture the entire contents of the stdin to a String? Also, would there be any security concerns if a user tries to pipe in an enormously large file? Is there a limit to how long the String can be? How can I safeguard against that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied the code of the `stdin.readLineSync()` and was able to modify it to fit my needs:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

String readInputSync({Encoding encoding: SYSTEM_ENCODING}) {
  final List input = [];
  while (true) {
    int byte = stdin.readByteSync();
    if (byte < 0) {
      if (input.isEmpty) return null;
      break;
    }
    input.add(byte);
  }
  return encoding.decode(input);
}

void main() {
  String input = readInputSync();
  myFunction(input); // Take the input as an argument to a function
}
```

I needed to read synchronously from the stdin in order to pause the program until the entire stdin (until the end of file or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) was read.

Thanks for all your help! I don't think I would have been able to figure it out without your help.

Answer (score 6):

The following program if used interactively will echo your input but capitalise each character.

You can also pipe a file to it.

```
dart upper_cat.dart < file.txt
```

This will output the file with every character capitalised.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {

  // Stop your keystrokes being printed automatically.
  stdin.echoMode = false;

  // This will cause the stdin stream to provide the input as soon as it
  // arrives, so in interactive mode this will be one key press at a time.
  stdin.lineMode = false;

  var subscription;
  subscription = stdin.listen((List<int> data) {

    // Ctrl-D in the terminal sends an ascii end of transmission character.
    // http://www.asciitable.com/
    if (data.contains(4)) {
      // On my computer (linux) if you don't switch this back on the console
      // will do wierd things.
      stdin.echoMode = true;

      // Stop listening.
      subscription.cancel();
    } else {

      // Translate character codes into a string.
      var s = LATIN1.decode(data);

      // Capitalise the input and write it back to the screen.
      stdout.write(s.toUpperCase());
    }
  });

}
```

There is also the [console](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/console) library to help with this kind of stuff. I haven't tried it, but give it a shot and report back ;)

The following example handles UTF8 input - the example above requires 1 byte characters as input.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {

  stdin.echoMode = false;
  stdin.lineMode = false;

  var subscription;
  subscription = stdin
    .map((List<int> data) {
      if (data.contains(4)) {
        stdin.echoMode = true;
        subscription.cancel();
      }
      return data;
    })
    .transform(UTF8.decoder)
    .map((String s) => s.toUpperCase())
    .listen(stdout.write);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Greg! Thanks for your suggestion. I couldn't quite figure out how to modify your code to fit my needs. See my comment to Günter's solution. Basically, I'm trying to do something like `String input = stdin.readLineSync()`, but be able to save multiple lines instead of just one. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about the problem you are trying to solve. i.e. A function can listen for input and return a string when a Ctrl+D arrives. Or a program can wait for a newline character and return a string containing the line. If a program is supposed to read multiple lines, how does it know it is done reading? Will it wait until it reads an empty line? Or will in wait until it reads a line with the word "end" on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:async' show Future, Stream, StreamSubscription;
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;

void main() {
  StreamSubscription subscr = io.stdin.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data) => 
      print(data));
}
```

You can control whether more data should be received or not with

```dart
subscr.pause();
subscr.resume();
```

Listen on stdin passes data in chunks of 16kb if I remember correctly (io buffer size defined by Dart) this allows you to receive the amount of data you can process.
If you want to keep one big string in memory you need to have that memory available.

See also
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343041/217408 (set VM memory)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691502/217408
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28039661/217408

Comment: Thanks, Günter. I tried your suggestion, but I'm still not sure how this can capture the stdin to a String in Dart. Can you expand on your answer a bit more? Thanks, again!

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want a more specific answer please provide more information about what you try to accomplish and what exactly causes you troubles.

Comment: Hey, Günter. Sorry I'm late getting back to you on this. Your suggestion works, but I was not able to modify it to meet my needs. Basically, I'm trying to do something like `String input = stdin.readLineSync()`, but be able to save multiple lines instead of just one. For background, I'm working on a CSS pre-processor. So I need to save the stdin to a string, then process the string.